# eclipse cdt cygwin gdb stackdump is not a core dump File format not recognized

Tags: c++, gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

I tried below commmand after running my application in debug mode on eclipse cdt 
and which gave a segmentation with generating file  TestC++.exe.stackdump

```
gdb ./Debug/TestC++.exe ./TestC++.exe.stackdump
```

> Error:
>   "/cygdrive/c/Users/Achilles/workspace/c++/TestC++/./TestC++.exe.stackdump"
>   is not a core dump: File format not recognized

TestC++.exe.stackdump file content :

```
Exception: STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION at eip=004017F5
eax=6779632F ebx=0024CC4C ecx=00000000 edx=6C7049CC esi=2006135A edi=611CCFB2
ebp=0024CBB8 esp=0024CBA0 program=C:\Users\Achilles\workspace\c++\TestC++\Debug\TestC++.exe, pid 1072, thread main
cs=001B ds=0023 es=0023 fs=003B gs=0000 ss=0023
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0024CBB8  004017F5 (0024CC18, 6779632F, 00000000, 00000000)
0024CBD8  00401806 (0024CC18, 20061318, 0024FD24, 61028993)
0024CBF8  00401806 (0024CC18, 0024CC4C, 00000000, 6108FCE0)
0024CC28  004011CA (00000001, 0024CC4C, 200280E8, 6100833B)
0024CD18  6100839A (00000000, 0024CD74, 61007410, 00000000)
End of stack trace
```

Answer (score 1):

The options are:

1. Get your compile and link to use g++'s `-g` option and run the program under `gdb` (with or without CDT's debug perspective) and let the debugger catch the access violation when it happens.
2. Use cygwin's `addr2line` utility. You run ldd on your program to translate the crash address to the name of a DLL or executable. Then you invoke `addr2line` with the first argument set to the path to the DLL that has the given address range, and the second argument is the address of the crash. It may be necessary to install via Cygwin's setup utility any debug packages that pertain to libraries used by your code, if the crash site is not within your own code. In any case the easy case for using `addr2line` is when the crash site is in your code. But you can in fact use it when your use of a library causes a crash within the library.
3. Isolate the issue using printf's or a real logging system.

Comment: my g++ options -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x

Comment: @user2713375 The `-g3` option should be excellent for use with gdb from the command line or gdb with the Eclipse CDT gdb interface. `-g3` just means that the compiler adds more information about your program to the executable for the debugger to use.

Comment: @user2713375 I recommend then that you add to your question more details of what you tried. The comment you just made is not specific about what is working and what is not. Did you try using gdb from the command line? Did you try using CDT's debug perspective? Did you try adding logging as a way to track down the problem without using a debugger?